# Confused about MongoDB / Mongoose models

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I swear, not but a short time ago, I could access model properties directly.
Now, as of summer 2015, it seems I have to access model properties through the _doc property, like so:

`model._doc.password` instead of `model.password`

one weird thing that is happening, is that this function to compare passwords was pretty much copied verbatim from the web:

```
 userSchema.methods.validatePassword = function (password, cb) {
        bcrypt.compare(password, this.passwordHash, function (err, res) {
            return cb(err, res ? true : false);
        });
    };
```

`this.passwordHash` should pull the passwordHash property from the model. However, when I debug, passwordHash is not a property of `this`, it is property of `this._doc`.

Am I going crazy or did it used to be another way with Mongoose and MongoDB?

Comment: You shouldn't ever need to access `_doc` as that should be considered private data of the model instance.  Be sure `passwordHash` is in your schema definition.

Comment: ok I see, pretty crazy, is there a good link to read about how mongoose handles this?

Comment: The [docs on schemas](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) describe the concept.

Comment: ok thanks @JohnnyHK I will distill and post an answer